# Audio not playing with JAR File

Tags: java, audio, jar, resources

I created a project that plays audio within the netbeans IDE. Those audio files were placed in the Classes folder.
Although when I created it as a JAR file, it was unable to locate the audio files. I even copy and pasted the files inside the new dist folder.
Here is a snippet of code:

```
    private void playSound39() 
{
  try
  {
/**Sound player code from:
http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-audio-example-java-au-play-sound    
*/      
    // the input stream portion of this recipe comes from a javaworld.com article.
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("./beep39.wav");
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Audio file not found!");
  }   
}
```

Comment: try to run the jar from cmd or from terminal to know the exception

Comment: Place the audio file in the src directory of your project;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to embedd the audio file in your program it's must be placed inside the `src` folder in a package.
For example I'll demonstrate a code I use to set icons to buttons (should work for audio files as well) :
While creating the JFrame I wrote :

```
jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/GUI/Icon/PatientBig.png")));
```

I have in my project a package called `GUI` with a subpackage called `Icons` where my icons exist and they all are in `src` folder.
When you using `getClass().getResource` function , I prefer to use an absolute path.
After seeing your respone I have noticed that you keep using `.` in the begining of the class path, I copied the snippet you published and removed the `.` from the begining of the path and placed my audio file `bark.wav` in the `src` folder in the default package and it worked

```
public class test {

    private void playSound39() {
        try {
            /**
             * Sound player code from:
             * http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-audio-example-java-au-play-sound
             */
            // the input stream portion of this recipe comes from a javaworld.com article.
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/bark.wav");
            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Audio file not found!");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new test().playSound39();
    }
}
```

Then I placed the audio file inside a package called `test1` and modified the path in `getResourceAsStream` function and again it worked:

```
public class test {

    private void playSound39() {
        try {
            /**
             * Sound player code from:
             * http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-audio-example-java-au-play-sound
             */
            // the input stream portion of this recipe comes from a javaworld.com article.
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test1/bark.wav");
            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Audio file not found!");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new test().playSound39();
    }
}
```

The Most important thing is to remove `.` from the path

Comment: I pasted the audio inside the src folder and created another JAR file from the Project Properties menu again. Although, the time stamp on the JAR file states it was from earlier today. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, Nasser. Removing the `.` character allowed it work. Also I pasted the audio inside the src folder. I forgot to click "Clean and Build Project" earlier which didn't update the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/beep39.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bypass use of the InputStream. When running the getAudioInputStream method, using InputStream as a parameter triggers markability and resetability tests on the audio file. Audio files usually fail these tests. If you create your AudioInputStream with a URL or File parameter, these tests are circumvented. I prefer URL as it seems more robust and can "see into" jars.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("./beep39.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

Then, in a while loop, you would execute a read method on the AudioInputStream and send the data to a SourceDataLine.

The Java Tutorials covers this in their [audio trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html). This link jumps into the middle of the tutorials.

AFAIK, there is no "AudioPlayer" in the Java 7 SDK.

Comment: I had to use "/audio/filename.wav" instead of "src/audio/filename.wav"